# How to add margin to table in jquery datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I need to add some space between table, table length and table pagination.
Like this:[enter link description here](https://monosnap.com/file/Z1wCjTt1FwOiDstMrMe7ZFmyAiVALt)
This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data-table').dataTable({
            bFilter: false,
            aoColumnDefs: [
              {
                  bSortable: false,
                  aTargets: [1, 2],

              },
            {
                'bVisible': false,
                aTargets: [4],
            },
            {

                "targets": 0,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                {
                    return '<a href = "@(Url.Action("EmployeeAccount", "Company"))?EmployeeId=' + full[4] + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            },
            ]
        })
    });
```

Html:

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover little_margin_table" id="data-table" width="100%">
/...
                    </table>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You must set margin for table in div wrapper of table, example:

if you have table with id `userTables`, use selector `#userTables_wrapper` in css to set table margin.Why? see screenshot below:

[image]

Datatables auto generate div wrapper with id `your_table_id + "_wrapper"`.This wrapper is parent for your table.

Comment: my dataTable was getting updated multiple times, so the table id was also changing. I applied css using class instead of id and it worked.

`.dataTables_wrapper {
margin: 20px 0;
}`

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS:

```
#data-table {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

But, to be honest, your question is lacking any HTML and/or CSS. It's also blatantly non-researched, as adding margins between HTML elements can be understood without posting a question on SO.

In any case, what the CSS does it create a top and bottom margin of `20px` for your table.

Comment: I tried to do so, but unfortunately it is not working. When the table is created jquery assigns it the other styles which cover all my styles.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Datatables Styling](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator) to create styles for your datatable or modify your css by own:

```
table.dataTable {
margin: 20px 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS rules:

```
table.dataTable {
  margin-top:2em !important;  
  margin-bottom:2em !important;  
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tn6cuqwe/1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
table.dataTable {
     padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the CSS tricks fail and you want a right-side margin, you can add a small blank column on the right using:

```
  <th> &nbsp; </th> ... <td> &nbsp; </td>"
```

It looks a little dodgy, but effectively solves the problem.  In some browsers the scroll-bar otherwise covers part of the right-most column in wide tables.